# Vb.net how can I convert decimal value1.9 to 1.09 instead of 1.90

Tags: .net, vb.net

I want to compare the product version 1.9 to 1.10 but I am unable to do so as 1.9 is considered as 1.90.

Comment: The problem is not specific to 2 decimals, what about vs 1.19 vs v1.192? Your best option is probably to create a new Version class implementing IComparable and handling the comparison logic

Comment: Yup - basically if the value isn't really "a single decimal number" but "a dot-separated sequence of integers" that's how you should parse it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Version Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.version?view=netcore-3.1)

```
    Dim ver1 As New Version("1.9")
    Dim ver2 As New Version("1.10")
    If ver1 = ver2 Then
        Stop
    ElseIf ver1 < ver2 Then
        Stop
    ElseIf ver1 > ver2 Then
        Stop
    End If
```